# choosing assets sailsjs

Tags: javascript, express, sails.js

I've started using SailsJS for a small web app and so far it's great.
However I'm struggling with the assets and layout.

Basically I would like to be able to use different type of assets (groups of css files) depending on the page.
For this, I wrote 2 different layouts, each should includes the correct css files.
However, when I add those files in the `config/assets.js` files there all bundled together.
Is there a way to specifiy in my layout which assets i want to use ?
I know you can specify `assets.js` or `assets.styles` but I would like to be able to create my own group .

I also tried to put those assets in a different directory (public for example) and load them manually in my layout. It's still not working because the server doesn't want to 'serve' them.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glad you're liking Sails :)

For now, you can (a) bring in all styles all the time and make only the relevant ones apply (b) use another tool (like Grunt) to bundle assets like you would in a vanilla node.js project or (c) link the stylesheets manually (put them in your public folder).

As for the roadmap-- the community is working on more options for serving templates/styles/client-side logic.  There's an open spec here:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/240

Hope that helps!

Comment: As stated in my question, I tried the public folder but it didn't work. Have I been doing something wrong then ?

Comment: To make the public folder work, you put your assets in there and link to them manually from the layout.ejs file.  E.g.:

cp foo.css /path/to/sailsProject/public
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/foo.css">

Comment: To bring in all assets and make only the relevant ones apply, I'm just referring to structuring your styles and markup in such a way that all the stylesheets can be loaded at once and the pages will still render correctly.  Hope that helps!

Comment: putting stuff in public didn't work because i put 'public' in the path ... That works with now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else comes across this; in recent versions of sails the asset pipeline is built around grunt by default (I haven't used sails before 0.10.x).

You can add your own exports in `tasks/pipeline.js` and link those to the appropriate location in `tasks/config/sails-linker.js`. E.g. you could have a `views/public` folder and tell sails-linker to inject `publicCSS` vars there. Then adjust your `layout.ejs` so that it imports the styles/javascript from whichever folder.