# How can I include javascript assets selectively in SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

In a Sails.js application, how can I include javascript assets selectively?

For instance, if I have an admin page and admin.js lives inside the assets/js directory. How do I keep the admin.js from loading on the public index page?

I'm aware that I could move the js out to the public directory, and include the script in my admin view's template. But I'm still unable to include it after the **assets.js()** call inserts it's javascript. I need it to be inserted after the **sails.io.js** script is loaded.

Is there any way to selectively load scripts and still have access to the **sails.io.js** which is automatically included with the **assets.js()** function call? Is there a better paradigm for this kind of situation?

EDIT:

Since the release of SailsJS 0.9 and the restructuring of the asset management system, this question doesn't really apply anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Sailsjs uses asset-rack to serve /assets. With the default layout page, sailsjs serves pages that look like (dummy2.js is included with an explicit < script >):

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/mixins/sails.io-d338eee765373b5d77fdd78f29d47900.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/dummy0-1cdb8d87a92a2d5a02b910c6227b3ca4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/dummy1-8c1b254452f6908d682b9b149eb55d7e.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="/public/dummy2.js"></script>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

So sailsjs does not concatenate files (at least not in development mode). sails.io (socket-io) is always included before /assets/js in layout, and before < script > on the page.

It looks like your admin.js is expecting a condition which sails.io has not yet set, perhaps its negotiating a transport with the server? Try waiting for the condition to be set.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the same version of sails. But the default layout page includes the sails.io.js before the closing body tag.

Comment: Indeed, sails.io should be served with a < script >. You can place that tag where you need it to properly load your assets.

Answer (score 1):

> > In a Sails.js application, how can I include javascript assets selectively?

I selectively load js assets using a wrapper around assets.js(). This snippet uses Jade's "-" and "!{...}". EJS would instead use "<%...%>" and "<%=...%>"

```
<!-- JavaScript and stylesheets from your assets folder are included here -->
!{assets.css()}
-function selectAssets (assetsjs, files, ifInclude) {
-  return assetsjs.split('\n').reduce(function (prev, curr, i) {
-    var frag = curr.match(/src="\/assets\/js\/\w{1,}\-/);
-    if(frag) {
-      var file = frag[0].substring(16, frag[0].length - 1);
-      if ((files.indexOf(file) === -1) == ifInclude) { return prev; }
-   }
-   return prev + curr + '\n';
-  }, '');
-}
//!{assets.js()} this line is replaced by:
!{selectAssets(assets.js(), ['dummy1', 'dummy5', 'dummy6'], false)}
```

The above would not include /assets/js/dummy1.js, dummy5, dummy6 with the layout. If you wanted to include dummy1 and dummy5 on a particular page, you would place

```
!{selectAssets(assets.js(), ['dummy1', 'dummy5'], true)}
```

on that page.

Note: The code assumes file name don't contain "-". Its straighforward to generalize for css and templates. sails-io would be a special case for mixins.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but since people are still looking for this.

Sails has a folder called tasks in the root after you create a new project.

The file you are looking for is

> pipeline.js

That file holds a variable called `jsFilesToInject`

```
// Client-side javascript files to inject in order
// (uses Grunt-style wildcard/glob/splat expressions)
var jsFilesToInject = [

  // Load sails.io before everything else
  // 'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  'js/sails.io.js'


  // Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

  // All of the rest of your client-side js files
  // will be injected here in no particular order.
  'js/**/*.js'
];
```

Just put your script that you want loaded before sails.io.js.

This is relevant for sails 0.11.x

another way that is valid is to create a views/partials folder

and create a new file like mapScripts.ejs
drop the script tags there and in your view use

```
<% include ../partials/mapScripts %>
```

Comment: How can I use this in html file? I simple have app.html under views folder and when I use like src="/js/bundle.js" it does not work.

Comment: did you put the javascript file in the assets/js folder? I'm assuming you have the latest sails.js installed so if you happend to follow an old tutorial the 'sails new <your project name>' command with '--linker' might mess up assets being served correctly it is not needed anymore to use the flag. Also it is not an html file it is an .ejs file that could also mess up the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you put a condition  in template. :)

or add another "block" for your js.

```
extends ../layout

block body
    <h1>hello</h1>

block jsscripts
    <scripts> ..... </script>
```

Comment: Putting a condition in the admin template would still cause the script to be loaded **before** the sails.io.js script. How do I get it to load after? Would I have to move the `<%- assets.js() %>` line from layout.ejs out into my admin template? That would cause me to have to do the same for all my views.

Comment: Im not sure, but i think socketio loads first. Maybe you can add a listener to check if socketio is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of your question about where included files are located.

In 0.10 version order of the files is set in file `tasks/values/injectedFiles.js` as I recall in previous versions it was determined in `Gruntfile.js` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add reference of your custom file in tasks/pipeline.js

```
var jsFilesToInject = [
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',
  'js/**/*.js',
  'js/yourcustomFile.js'
];
```